# determine if two priority_queues are equal

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I want to check if two std::priority_queue (lets call it PQ)(which has vector as underlying containder) are equal. What I have in mind is to somehow get access to the underlying vector and then use std::equal. The interface PQ provides has no way of checking the equality. The naive way would be to pop each element from the copies (because I don't want to lose the original PQs) of those two PQs and check one by one but the size of my PQ will often be very large in my current (time sensitive) application so it is not favourable.

EDIT

It has been declared like this:

```
typedef std::priority_queue<std::pair<int,int>, std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >, greater_than> PRIORITY_Q;
```

where greater_than is a struct(which has a function and some other data) which handles the comparision.

What I want is:
 suppose we have

```
PRIORITY_Q a;
PRIORITY_Q b;
```

then we fill in the queues a and b with values.

I want to check if a == b (by overloading ==).

Comment: You cannot test for equality the underlying type. There can be different underlying representations for exactly the same priority queue, depending on how it was built. You could get the underlying type, copy it, sort it and then compare... but this kind of beats the whole purpose of a priority queue

Comment: Can you elaborate on the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you really need access to the underlying container, consider using a vector, and calling `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, etc., on it. But, as @DavidRodríguez-dribeas said, that still won't give an easy way to check for equality.

Comment: Comparing by popping may not work either - what happens if the two PQ have the same two entries at the same priority level, but get popped in a different order?

Comment: @MartinJames But the root element always gets popped. So I think if they have same structure then same elements will be popped.

Comment: OK, how about you checksum in and out objects on each queue.   You can then compare the checksums, (or some other large hash, whatever).